# Esper Repeated On-Demand Queries

Tags: java, esper

Reading the Esper documentation I would like to make use of on-demand queries.

However, is it possible to create an on-demand query that runs for a certain amount of time?

Does Esper support this or would I need to write my own implementation, I know I should use prepared statements for repeated executions.

Esper Documentation: http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.0.0/doc/reference/en/html/api.html#api-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On on-demand query that runs for a certain amount of time would seem to be the same as a Esper continuous query. What is the point?

Comment: The point would be that in my use case, a user will run an on-demand query to return some data that will be plotted on a real-time graph continuously (Perhaps until they say stop). An Esper continuous query would be ideal but I am under the impression that these cannot be injected at runtime? I am wondering if it would just be easier to  store a list of these on demand queries and then just have a thread that keeps injecting them into the Esper runtime engine.

Comment: Sure continuous queries can be injected at runtime. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Had a quick look at the API and its not so obvious to me how this can be done? Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: epAdministrator.createEPL(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a continuous query which only works at certain times. If you want an event to trigger only between to points in time, say only on the first of january between 10 and 11 am ,here's a way to do it:

`select * from pattern [timer:at(0, 10:11, 1, 1,*) -> every MyEvent]`

You can specify a time range with [`timer:at`](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.11.0/doc/reference/en-US/html/event_patterns.html#pattern-atom-time) and use `->` (followed by) to only make the event trigger inside a certain time range. The example above only works at the first first january between 10 and 11 after you specified it. So it's sort of a on-demand query. It assumes the event you're interested in is called `MyEvent`.

You can also use this approach for recurring time periods. For example, the following query allows `MyEvent` to trigger every monday during april:

`select * from pattern [every timer:at(0, 0:23, *, 4, 1) -> every MyEvent]`

Another way to do it would be using the [Esper date-time methods](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.11.0/doc/reference/en-US/html/datetimereference.html). This allows for more control and more complicated queries, but you need your time information to come from the event itself (or from another one).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dax, I was not aware that Esper patterns could be scheduled like this which is good to know. I think for my use case however, I will be needing an easy way to replay on-demand queries continuously. To be fair its probably something I can implement myself ,just wondered if Esper had any facility to do this.